# Shinobi Stacked column series chart data point

Tags: graph, stack, shinobi

I want to plot stacked column graph through Shinobi.

Please referer attached screen shot for desired graph.

Can anyone please suggest how to pass data point for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am a developer at Shinobi Controls.

To get columns to stack you need to create a series for each column you wish to stack.

To get the series to stack, you must set each series' "stackIndex" property to the same value.

For example, in your image you will need 5 SChartColumnSeries with their  "stackIndex" value set to the same value, lets say 1.

Now you can add one datapoint for each series with the same X value but with different Y values.